# Production build of angular 2 application on nginx server

Tags: angular, nginx, angular2-routing

After making an Angular 2 production build on nginx server, an issue arises:

- I am on a /route1
- Refresh the page
- I am still on /route1
- I click to go to /route2
- Instead of going to /route2 I am redirected to the /home

If I don't refresh the page (see step 2), everything works just fine.

Angular 2 application is running without problems locally on the development server. I guess this has to do with some settings on nginx server?

**EDIT**

On Apache server, the page is working after putting that inside .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN ServeStatic

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

# END ServeStatic
```

However, on nginx server it is **not working** although I put that inside the configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/page-name.com/html/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name page-name.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

Is there any difference? Did I forget anything?

Comment: You need to configure nginx to support HTML5 pushState. There are dozens of similar questions with more details.

Comment: I've already included this inside the <location> tag: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; but this does not solve the problem. Is there anything else to configure? Please point me to the similar question. Thanks!